# Flutter Riverpod v1.0 - state not updating with StateNotifier List

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I migrated from RiverPod 0.4x to 1.0 stable and now this StateNotifier no longer updates state even though the `move()` function is being called (debugPrint shows the call) when animation ends. This was working in 0.4x, but obviously in the improved 1.0 RiverPod I've not fully migrated.

What am I missing here for RiverPod 1.0 to update state when the state is a List?

```dart
final animateCoversStateNotifierProvider = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<
    AnimateCoversStateNotifier,
    List<CoverAlignment>>((ref) => AnimateCoversStateNotifier());
```

```dart
class AnimateCoversStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<CoverAlignment>> {
  AnimateCoversStateNotifier() : super([]);

  void addCover({
    required CoverAlignment alignment,
  }) =>
      state.add(alignment);

  void move({
    required int cover,
    bool? readyToOpen,
    bool? speechBalloonVisible,
    Duration? animatedOpacityDuration,
    bool? removeSpeechBalloonPadding,
  }) {
    debugPrint('move cover called');
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
      if (mounted) {
        state[cover].removeSpeechPadding = speechBalloonVisible != true;
        state[cover].speechBalloonOpacity =
            speechBalloonVisible == true ? kMaxSpeechBalloonOpacity : 0.0;
        state[cover].x = CoverAlignment.randomDouble();
        state[cover].y = CoverAlignment.randomDouble();
        state[cover].curve = CoverAlignment.getCurve();
        state[cover].seconds = CoverAlignment.randomSeconds();
        state[cover].degrees = CoverAlignment.randomIntInRangeWithMinimum(
          min: 0,
          max: 45,
        );
        /// This was required to update state using RiverPod 0.4x, but no longer works in 
        /// RiverPod 1.0.
        state = state;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**In my build screen body I am use `watch` to react to the notifier's changes.**

```dart
/// Display covers
final List coverAlignment =
    ref.watch(animateCoversStateNotifierProvider);
```

**EDIT: Creating a Freezed class as Remi in comments suggests**

```dart
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:myapp/app/corral/models/cover_alignment_model.dart';

part 'animate_covers.freezed.dart';

class AnimateCovers extends StateNotifier<List<CoverAlignment>>
    with _$AnimateCovers {
  factory AnimateCovers() = _AnimateCovers;

  void addCover({
    required int cover,
    required CoverAlignment alignment,
  }) {
    state.insert(cover, alignment);
  }

  void move({
    required int cover,
    bool? readyToOpen,
    bool? speechBalloonVisible,
    Duration? animatedOpacityDuration,
    bool? removeSpeechBalloonPadding,
  }) {
    /// What do I do here?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing:

```dart
state = state
```

was never supposed to work.

You're not supposed to mutate the existing state. You're supposed to clone the state

Instead do something like:

```dart
state[cover] = state[cover].copyWith(
  removeSpeechPadding: speechBalloonVisible != true,
  ...
),
```

You can generate this `copyWith` method using [Freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed)

Comment: Looking at Freezed https://pub.dev/packages/freezed Remi. In my post I've added my beginning attempt at creating a Freezed class of my AnimateCoversStateNotifier class. I'm lost on how to do this though. If you can provide some code it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Remi, still stuck on this. I've tried several different things and when the state is a list it doesn't appear that RiverPod 1.0 is notifying listeners about List state changes. Even if I could get `copyWith` working I don't understand how that would cause the StateNotifier to emit changes in the List.

Comment: I did find a workaround since I can't get state to update in the statenotifier. I using a StatefulBuilder and am able to call setState(). Anyway, not sure if this is an issue in RiverPod 1.0. Thanks for all your incredible work Remi.